# Is Greedy Algorithm always best for choosing proper indexes for database table?

Tags: database, database-design, database-indexes

In "Database Systems: The Complete Book" written by Garcia-Molina, Ullman, Widom, in chapter dedicated to indexes, it is written that **the greedy algorithm for choosing best indexes for given database is effective**. By greedy they mean choosing the best index based on some analysis, then repeat analysis for remaining indexes (including info about newly added index in previous step), choosing the best one again, etc.

We must have in mind, according to authors, that using one index or another can also affect other indexes' performance.

I am just curious, is the **"greedy way"** only effective or maybe also guaranteed to be optimal? 
Why is it effective/optimal?

Comment: Greedy methods in general are not optimal, and this is true also in this case. The optimal solution for the index selection requires an exponential algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I can also accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySQL, the "greedy" method is not used at all (as far as I can tell).  Instead, it uses statistics, plus probes into the BTrees to decide what it is likely to "cost" for each index.  Then it takes the cheapest.

It is impractical to simulate the "cost" model in your head; instead, see the following, which provides some general rules that almost always work:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

No method is "guaranteed to be optimal".  Many methods (greedy/cost/cookbook/etc) are *usually* optimal.

If an algorithm spends too much time deciding what is optimal, well that takes away from the time to actually perform the query!  It's sort of the "heisenberg uncertainty principle" of optimizing queries.

Sometimes the "optimal" is to ignore all the indexes and simply scan the table.  This is because bouncing back and forth between the index and the data *may* make using an index *slower*.  This forum is littered with people who don't understand that and ask "Why didn't MySQL use my index?"